# How to convert an Windows service to an Executable application(console) Exe?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-services, exe

I have a windows service. It works fine. But I want to convert it to a exe and invoke it from some other service with command line args. I see most articles on converting a exe into service but not service into exe.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the process will be:

1. Create the new exe project (probably a console application)
2. In the Main method you can put the same code that you have on the OnStart() method of your service.

As services have short time to start, usually only basic initialization steps are performed in the OnStart and the "real" execution is deferred (by using a timer or until specific I/O operation is received). Executable programs does not have this restriction so maybe this could be refactored too.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an application, which could be used as stand alone and as service worker. For this, you would need to create a new project and move all non-service related code. You would need to refactor start-up code to accept arguments. This way you will be able to use this application as Worker application in the service you have. But if there will be no start-up arguments it will ruin as regular application.

For example, when running as service worker you will start the process in your service with startup path  like this:

```
"c:\program files\myCompany\MyApplication\app.exe /runAs sysAdmin /service 1 /jobId 123"
```

Your service itself will now only contain code that finds the "work to do" and starts the "Worker".

Your worker when runs as standalone will display either a black screen for console or a form for win app.